# How to get the number of music files our device having

Tags: iphone

iam developing one application.In that i need to get the how many music files are there in my device.Iam using the MPMediaPickerController for selecting the music files.But i want to get the number of files that device having with open and select the files from the picker.So please tell me how to get that number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all the songs use the following

```
MPMediaQuery *allSongsQuery= [MPMediaQuery songsQuery];
NSArray *songs = [allSongsQuery collections];
```

If you want open and select, you will have to do some more work

Comment: I written the code like MPMediaPickerController *picker =[[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes:MPMediaTypeMusic];
    picker.delegate      = self;
    picker.allowsPickingMultipleItems = YES;
    //picker.prompt      =@"Add songs to play";
    //[self presentModalViewController:picker animated: YES];
    MPMediaQuery *allSongsQuery= [MPMediaQuery songsQuery];
    NSArray *songs = [allSongsQuery collections];.But it gives the 0 objects in the array.